# Async pipe still returns null after triggering observable trough event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an angular component, displaying a rich text editor (tiptap v2) and the corresponding JSON output. After creating an observable from the `update` event provided by the editor, I want to initalize the editor with mock data. I would expect the editor to trigger an update event, which would then lead to the JSON data being displayed correctly. This doesn't work after initalization and the async pipe returns null. I could work around the issue by using rxjs `startWith` operator, but it seems wrong to initalize the observable seperately from the editor which it should be observing.

This is my template

```html
<div class="editor-window">
  <tiptap-editor [editor]="editor"></tiptap-editor>
</div>

<div style="margin-top: 15px">
  <b>JSON</b><br />
  <pre style="overflow: scroll">{{ editorJson$ | async | json }}</pre>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
</div>
```

And this is the corresponding component

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Editor } from '@tiptap/core';
import { StarterKit } from '@tiptap/starter-kit';
import { fromEvent, Observable, startWith } from 'rxjs';
import { dummyContent } from './dummy-content';

@Component({
  selector: 'nai-annotation-editor',
  templateUrl: './annotation-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./annotation-editor.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AnnotationEditorComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public editor: Editor;

  // Register editor 'update event' as observable
  public editorJson$: Observable<any> | undefined;

  constructor() {
    this.editor = new Editor({
      extensions: [
        StarterKit.configure({
          // support for three heading levels (max. is six)
          heading: {
            levels: [1, 2, 3],
          },
          // disable obsolete extensions
          blockquote: false,
          code: false,
          codeBlock: false,
          horizontalRule: false,
          strike: false,
        }),
      ],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editorJson$ = fromEvent(this.editor, 'update', (event) =>
      event?.editor.getJSON()
    ); //.pipe(startWith(dummyContent));
    this.editor.commands.setContent(dummyContent, true);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.editor.destroy();
  }
}
```

When moving the `editor.commands.setContent(...)` to `ngAfterViewInit()` it is displayed as expected, but I receive an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked` Error.

Also I can confirm that the observable is indeed returning a value by subscribing and outputting to console.log. So why is it not returned by async pipe?

I suspect this has something to do with the component lifecycle and async pipe but im not sure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truth is that you do not need observable at all:

```
export class AnnotationEditorComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public editor: Editor;

  public editorJson$: any;

  constructor() {
    this.editor = new Editor({
      extensions: [
        StarterKit.configure({
          // support for three heading levels (max. is six)
          heading: {
            levels: [1, 2, 3],
          },
          // disable obsolete extensions
          blockquote: false,
          code: false,
          codeBlock: false,
          horizontalRule: false,
          strike: false,
        }),
      ],
    });
    this.editor.on('update', (event) => {
        this.editorJson$ = event?.editor.getJSON();
    });
    this.editor.commands.setContent(dummyContent, true);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.editor.destroy();
  }
}

<div class="editor-window">
  <tiptap-editor [editor]="editor"></tiptap-editor>
</div>

<div style="margin-top: 15px">
  <b>JSON</b><br />
  <pre style="overflow: scroll">{{ editorJson$ | json }}</pre>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
</div>
```

Comment: that's true, but out of curiosity it would be nice to know what the issue with the observable is.

Comment: Most probably `fromEvent` fires before async pipe subscribes (you can add  `console.log` to `fromEvent` handler or put a break point), you have to use something like `ReplaySubject` to capture missing events.

Comment: That's probably the issue.  You could try adding `shareReplay(1)` to ensure you receive the last emission that occurred prior to your subscription: `this.editorJson$ = fromEvent(...).pipe(shareReplay(1))`